# Oracle external table logfile showing file not found when table not accessed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, loader, oracle11gr2, external-tables

We're using in Oracle 11g Release 2 an ORACLE_LOADER type external table to import data from a CSV file to a table. The external table has a dummy filename set for the LOCATION value, as the users will be entering the correct filename as a parameter when the package is run. The package code will then set the location via an ALTER statement.

There is only one package - and nothing else - using the external table, and that package is only run occasionally - say once a week. However, the external table's logfile is being updated about every 4 hours, saying the dummy file wasn't found (which, of course, it wouldn't be):

```
 LOG file opened at 05/10/13 22:00:12

 KUP-04040: file Dummy_Input_csv.csv in DIR_EXTDIR not found


 LOG file opened at 05/11/13 06:00:13

 KUP-04040: file Dummy_Input_csv.csv in DIR_EXTDIR not found


 LOG file opened at 05/11/13 10:05:07

 KUP-04040: file Dummy_Input_csv.csv in DIR_EXTDIR not found
```

From the Oracle documentation I've seen regarding managing and using external tables, I thought the external table's logfile would only be updated when the external table was actually used via a select statement to retrieve its data.

What else, outside of an actual SELECT, might cause an external table to go looking for its LOCATION file?

Comment: have you checked the privileges at OS level ? you need to have read permission on the file/folder for the user running the instance.

Comment: No one was running the instance at the time the errors were being logged, so permissions were not an issue. @mustaccio explained it, and we've turned off the logging to fix it (though David Aldridge's response would've been a great fix had the client decided to keep the logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be one of the scheduled jobs trying to access the table, such as the automatic collection of statistics. See if there are any jobs in dba_scheduler_jobs or dba_autotask_client that are scheduled to run at about the time you see the error.

Comment: +1 sounds like a reasonable assumption -- if there are (or even if there aren't come to think of it) the best way to stop it from happening would be to use DBMS_Stats.Lock_Table_Stats. That will stop gather_schema_stats from operating on the table unless force => true is set (in which case unset it)